# Synchronizing data between client and API (Database) .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, database, synchronization

I am currently working on a task where I need to synchronize the data, example:

Client makes a request to get data to the API (API has access to the database), client received the data and saves it to the list. That list is used for some time etc..... Then in the meanwhile another client accesses the same API and database and makes some changes... to the same table... After a while the first client want's to update his current data, since the table is quite big let's say 10 thousand records, grabbing the entire table again is inefficient. I would like to grab only the records that have been modified,deleted, or newly created. And then update the current list the client 1 has. if the client has no records, he classifies all of them as newly created (at start up) and just grabs them all. I would like to do as much checking on the client's side.

How would I go about this ? I do have fields such as Modified, LastSync, IsDeleted. So I can find the records I need but main issue is how to do it efficiently with minimal repetition.

At the moment I tried to get all the rows at first, then after I want to update (Synchronize) I get the minimal required info LastSync Modified IsDeleted Key, from the API, which I compare with what I have on the client and then send only keys of the rows that don't match to the server to get the entire values that match the keys. But I am not sure about efficiency of this also... not sure how to update the current list with those values efficiently the only way I can think of is using loop in loop to compare keys and update the list, but I know it's not a good approach.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work as long as you do not do the checks on the server side. There is always a chance that someone post between your api get call to server and you post call to server. Whatever test you can do at the client side, you can do it on the server side.

Comment: Well I do realize that, but I don't need perfect accuracy with synchronization I can miss the latest update that happened 1 second ago... not a big issues, but I want to offload resource usage from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DB and other setup, you could accomplish this by adding triggers on the tables/fields that you want to track in the database and setting up a cache (could use Redis, Memcached, Aerospike, etc.) and a cache refresh service . If something in the DB is added/updated/deleted, you can set up your trigger to write to a separate archive table in the DB. You can then set up a job from, e.g., Jenkins (or have a Kafka connector -- there are many ways to accomplish this) to poll the archive tables and the original table for changes based on an ID or date or whatever criteria you need. Anything that has changed will be refreshed and then written back to the cache. Then your API wouldn't be accessing the DB at all. It would just call the cache for the most recent data whenever a client requests it. Your separate service wold be responsible for synchronization of data, database access, and keeping the cache up to date.

Comment: This is a good answer if working with projects that are newer than 2005, I do appreciate the answer, but for now I need something that doesn't require me to remake the entire project, since it's just a simple patch, to speed one functionality, but I will definitely use it in the future. If nobody provides a direct answer I will mark this as a solution.